# PyTorch 1.0 loading VGGFace2 weights in Python3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pytorch

I am using Python3.7 and PyTorch 1.0 to develop a face recognition system. I want to use VGGFace2 Resnet50 pretrained model as described [here](https://github.com/ox-vgg/vgg_face2) as a feature extractor. I have downloaded the model and weights. 
I run the following codes as project readme says:

```
MainModel = imp.load_source('MainModel', 'resnet50_128_pytorch.py') 
model = torch.load('resnet50_128_pytorch.pth')
```

First line executed as expected but in the second line i got

> 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 1124: ordinal not in
>   range(128)

I searched in the Stackoverflow and Google and i saw that it may be about this model saved with Python2 and loading from Python3 creates a problem. Is there any way that i can solve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution which currently looks like it's working. It basically changes the pickle load with latin1 encoding.

```
from functools import partial
import pickle
pickle.load = partial(pickle.load, encoding="latin1")
pickle.Unpickler = partial(pickle.Unpickler, encoding="latin1")
MainModel = imp.load_source('MainModel', 'resnet50_ft_pytorch.py') 
model = torch.load('resnet50_ft_pytorch.pth', map_location=lambda storage, loc: storage, pickle_module=pickle)
```